# TypeError: dbConn.GetInstance is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript

I trying to create a common database connection class using typescript for my nodejs express application that returns the MongoDB database object as follows but I always get **TypeError: dbConn.GetInstance is not a function**

```
const config = require("config");
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

export class dbConn {

    private db = null;
    static url = config.database.uri;
    
    static options = {
        bufferMaxEntries:   0,
        reconnectTries:     5000,
        useNewUrlParser:    true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };
    
    private constructor() { }

    private static instance: dbConn;

    public static GetInstance() {//I also tried removing static keyword but still the error remains
        if (dbConn.instance == null)
        {
            dbConn.instance = new dbConn();
        }

        return dbConn.instance;
    }    

    public getDb() {
        if (dbConn.instance.db) {
            return dbConn.instance.db;
        }

        MongoClient.connect(dbConn.url, dbConn.options, function(err: any, db: any){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return null;
            }

            dbConn.instance.db = db.db(config.database.name);
            return dbConn.instance.db;
        });
    }
}
```

**Updated 01-Aug-2020**

I invoke the above instance from app.ts and my controllers as follows:

**app.ts file**

```
const dbConn = require('./utils/db/dbConn');
...//code removed for clarity
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
...//code removed for clarity
server.listen(port, ()=> {
    dbConn.GetInstance().getDb();//I get the error here
    console.log('Server running')
});
module.exports = app;
```

**my controller file**

```
getAll = async (pageNumber:any, pageSize:any) : Promise<PageResult<Team>> => {
        return new Promise<PageResult<Team>>(async function (resolve, reject){
            let result = new PageResult<Team>(pageSize, pageNumber);

            var dbo = dbConn.GetInstance().getDb();//same error here too.
            var query = {};
            
            var recCount = await dbo.collection("teams").find().count();
            
            if (recCount == 0) {
                result.IsSuccessful = true;
                result.ReasonForFailure = process.env.NO_RECORDS || "No record(s) to show.";
                return resolve(result);
            }

            if (pageSize == -1) { //-1 means to return all records
                dbo.collection("teams")
                .find(query)
                .sort({ name: 1 })
                .toArray(function(err: any, resultSet: any) {
                    if (err) {
                        result.IsSuccessful = false;
                        result.ReasonForFailure = err.message;
                        return reject(result);
                    } else {
                        result.IsSuccessful = true;
                        result.TotalRecords = recCount;
                        result.PageNumber = parseInt(pageNumber);
                        result.PageSize = parseInt(pageSize);
                        result.Data = resultSet;
                        return resolve(result);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                dbo.collection("teams")
                .find(query)
                .sort({ name: 1 })
                .skip((parseInt(pageNumber)-1)*parseInt(pageSize))
                .limit(parseInt(pageSize)).toArray(function(err: any, resultSet: any) {
                    if (err) {
                        result.IsSuccessful = false;
                        result.ReasonForFailure = err.message;
                        return reject(result);
                    } else {
                        result.IsSuccessful = true;
                        result.TotalRecords = recCount;
                        result.PageNumber = parseInt(pageNumber);
                        result.PageSize = parseInt(pageSize);
                        result.Data = resultSet;
                        return resolve(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Can you please assist what is wrong or what is the missing piece to get this to work?

Thanks,
Hemant.

Comment: Can you show us how you call `dbConn.GetInstance()`?

Comment: @eol, I have updated my original question adding code areas that shows how i try to invoke the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using `commonjs` as module-resolution strategy. Your import will be the problem in that case. Try changing it to:

```
const dbConn = require('./utils/db/dbConn').dbConn;
```

or

```
const { dbConn } = require('./utils/db/dbConn');
```

or

```
import {dbConn } from './utils/db/dbConn';
```

Here's a simple example to show what's going on. Consider this simple ts-class:

```
export class TestClass {
    static test():void {
        console.log("it works")
    }
}
```

It will be transpiled into:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.TestClass = void 0;
class TestClass {
    static test() {
        console.log("in workds");
    }
}
exports.TestClass = TestClass;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

If you then `require` this with `const TestClassModule = require('./test-class');`, `TestClassModule` will yield:

```
{ TestClass: [Function: TestClass] }
```

Hence, you need to use `const { TestClass } = require('./test-class');`.